# How to change Global Mule Configuration Elements at run time

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I need to change the global mule configuration elements at run time. How can I do it. I have a Web Service connector with values wsdl location, Service, port, address loaded by data sense. I need to change configuration of the global element at run time by disabling data sense. Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay, i think your idea about datasense is not correct. Datasense is just a helper to the developer to simulate data during development stage in anypoint studio. It does not populate data in run-time. You can always go and change the values in your webservice consumer manually or make it refer to a property file. I can help if you post your xml.

Answer (score 0):

I read that global elements can be configured only once. But I need to configure  it many a times in runtime!